# various small questions

Tags: texas-hold-em, live, learning

no matter where I've looked I've failed to grasp the concept of position/blinds, what's advantageous of a certain seat of the blinds and dealer button are going to change every turn anyway?

Can you raise the blinds?

Why would anyone fold when they can check if it's free just fold later on?

What happens if there is a set up like KKQ73 vs KKQ64 who would win?

And lastly isn't the best tactic to fold nearly every time and then check when you have a good hand  so you don't risk  risk any money and win the hand...? I think I'm missing some concepts

Comment: Consider separating these out into individual questions. It suits the site better and I know you'll get more detailed, focused responses that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantage is to be "on the button" -- the player furthest from the action. That is, with each cycle around the table, the blinds are first to act and the button is last. This is highly advantageous because the person last to act has seen a suggestion of each other player's interest in the pot (subject, of course, to bluffing and slow play).

Blind raising is dependent on where you're playing. In a tournament they typically get raised every 15 or 20 minutes -- a necessary action to ensure the tourney doesn't go on forever. In standard cash table games, the table has a fixed blind (but you can go play at other tables with different blinds).

It's foolish to fold if you have the option of checking. People sometimes do it without thinking though.

KKQ7x beats KKQ6y (where x is below 7, y is below 6, and there are no flushes in play).

When to check or fold takes far more explanation than a simple stack exchange question can address. There are literally volumes and volumes of books that attempt to answer that, but one issue to consider: boredom. I don't think you're going to enjoy poker playing the way you suggest.

Comment: do the buttons and blinds always alternate though? or are they in a fixed position? and also when you're the SB or BB can you raise it yourself if you want to? thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: The button shifts to the next player to the left after every hand, and the blinds follow. The blinds can never arbitrarily increase the blind amount; any change in blinds is structured in advance. That said, there is an option called a "straddle", something not available to the SB or BB. Generally it's only available to the player after the BB, who is (before the deal) allowed to place a blind bet that's twice the BB amount. This player is then permitted to act last on pre-flop action. (That is, they effectively double the blind and act like they're the BB that hand.)

Answer (score 0):

The "dealer's" seat is one where you can play aggressively.

You will be on that seat one time out of ten.

You can play "aggressively" that one time out of ten, and should play more cautiously the other nine times out of ten (actually, you also play aggressively in the "cut off" seat, the one to the right of the deal, so make that two times out of ten to play aggressively, and eight times out of ten to play cautiously.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can raise the big blind, if everyone is just in calls. It is true for no limits.If there is nobody raised then it can be fold, re raise or call. In other words it can be said that you miss the big blind and come later, if you missed the big blind or you leave it. When you come again you didn't want to wait you can join the game.